# Spring boot integration test with Oauth using JWT and PreAuthorized

Tags: jwt, integration-testing, userdetailsservice, oauth2resourceserver

Currently I have a security configuration using spring security with oauth2 resourceServer. Its all working fine with the JWT token this is my security filter chain looks like this:

```
httpSecurity.authorizeRequests()
                    .anyRequest().authenticated()
                    .and().cors()
                    .and().csrf()
                    .and().oauth2ResourceServer().jwt();
```

I need now to introduce this custom userDetailsService bean, in order to use preAuthorized annotation with custom roles and privileges:

```
@Bean
    public UserDetailsService userDetailsService(IIUserService iiUserService) {
        return new CustomUserDetailsService(new IIUserServiceFake());
    }

public class CustomUserDetailsService implements UserDetailsService {


    @Override
    public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String username) {
        //here I need to go to another micro-service to retrive the user roles/privileges and build a UserDetails Object
    }
```

Lets say I have this endpoint:

```
    @GetMapping("/custom")
    @PreAuthorize( "hasRole('ROLE_ADMIN')")
    public String getData(){
        return "I was able to see this endpoint";
    }
```

And my integration test looks like this:

```
@SpringBootTest(webEnvironment = SpringBootTest.WebEnvironment.RANDOM_PORT)
@ActiveProfiles("test")
public class ControllerTest {

    @LocalServerPort
    private int serverPort;

    @Autowired
    private TestRestTemplate testRestTemplate;

    @Test
    public void entitlementTest() {
        String uri = UriComponentsBuilder.fromHttpUrl("http://localhost").port(serverPort).path("/custom")
                .build().toUriString();
        ResponseEntity<String> forEntity = testRestTemplate.getForEntity(uri, String.class);
        assertEquals(200, forEntity.getStatusCodeValue());
    }
}
```

But now I want to be able to introduce roles/privileges with custom [UserDetailsService](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/api/org/springframework/security/core/userdetails/UserDetailsService.html)
Couple questions here:
1.- How do I mock the JWT resourceServer integration so that with the security enable during test the request looks authenticated.
2.- Using that UserDetailsService custom implementation how do I tell spring which field is the one to use because in my case i have a custom field comming from the token which is not call "username", lets say its called "custom_user_name".

Bassically I want to be able to test my controller that uses JWT token authentication with PreAuthorized annotation, using SpringBootTest

I already look [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31641562/spring-oauth-and-boot-integration-test) but still haven figure out a clean way to do this,

Again i dont want to change how the authentication is handle(JWT) but, have a custom way to determine if a user have the roles in my DB and being able to test that using integration test.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I need now to introduce this custom userDetailsService bean, in order to use preAuthorized annotation with custom roles and privileges

What you need is reading [the manual](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/reference/servlet/oauth2/resource-server/jwt.html#oauth2resourceserver-jwt-authorization-extraction) and a `Converter<Jwt, AbstractAuthenticationToken>` bean (like `JwtAuthenticationConverter` with proper configuration or an implementation of your own).

In your tests, if you use `MockMvc` instead of `TestRestTemplate`, then you can use `SecurityMockMvcRequestPostProcessors.jwt()` to setup the security-context for you (without an authorization server to be up and running). You could also have a look at this [lib I wrote](https://github.com/ch4mpy/spring-addons#unit-tests), it provides with test annotations similar to `@WithMockUser`, but for OAuth2. Sample integration test taken from [there](https://github.com/ch4mpy/spring-addons/blob/master/samples/webmvc-jwt-default/src/test/java/com/c4_soft/springaddons/samples/webmvc_jwtauthenticationtoken/SampleApiIntegrationTest.java):

```java
@SpringBootTest(webEnvironment = WebEnvironment.RANDOM_PORT)
@AutoConfigureMockMvc
class SampleApiIntegrationTest {

    @Autowired
    MockMvc api;

    @Test
    @WithAnonymousUser
    void givenRequestIsAnonymous_whenGetGreet_thenUnauthorized() throws Exception {
        api.perform(get("/greet")).andExpect(status().isUnauthorized());
    }

    @Test
    @WithJwt("ch4mp.json")
    void givenUserIsCh4mp_whenGetGreet_thenOk() throws Exception {
        api.perform(get("/greet")).andExpect(content().string("Hello ch4mp! You are granted with [USER_ROLES_EDITOR, ROLE_AUTHORIZED_PERSONNEL]."));
    }
}
```

The `@WithJwt` above uses the authentication converter (an implementation of `Converter<Jwt, ? extends AbstractAuthenticationToken>`, `JwtAuthenticationConverter` by default in Spring Boot) to build the `Authentication` in stance and populate test security context, using a JSON payload in test classpath.

Comment: Thanks ch4mp (sorry for the delay) that worked fine (addind a custom implementation of Converter<Jwt, AbstractAuthenticationToken>). One follow up is that I guess what I really wanted in the test area is to NOT mock the security context but have a real security integration test.. Thanks again. very useful answer.

Comment: Using a "real" security context requires a "real" token which can be issued only by a "real" authorization server (recent "test containers" features help with that) and involve some network exchanges. **This is way slower and quite more complicated** than using MockMvc. I would use an authorization server only in end-to-end tests (involving all stacks composing the application), not when writing a Spring app integration tests (tests of all `@Components` wired together): using `@WithJwt`, tokens JSON payload and the authentication converter is, in my opinion, a much better solution.

Comment: Also, end-to-end test frameworks (like protractor), are usually better tools to run `authorization_code` flow which require user interaction with a minimum of screen and keyboard (it's more complicated when Multi-Factor Authentication is configured on the authorization server). Of course, you can configure a few test clients with `client_credentials` (each with the same roles as one of your test users) to rather easily get access tokens in your JUnit tests with test containers, but this is not your "real" flow anymore and still more complicated and much slower than `MockMvc` with `@WithJwt`.

Comment: I see, thanks @ch4mp . PD I guess having testContainers would be nice.